# cocoa, table view with core data datasource

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am absolutely new to cocoa development so please don't chastise me for asking this.

Do I have to uses bindings? I know it saves a lot of code, but since I'm learning I'd really prefer to set everything up in the code.

My goal is to populate a table view with the entities I fetch from core data.  I've created a custom controller class for my main window view.  I also have some code to fetch my category entites

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Category"
                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjectsArray = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjectsArray == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error occured fetching categories: %@", error);
}


for (Category *cat in fetchedObjectsArray) {
    NSLog(@"categories %@", cat.name);
}
```

I know I have to implement the delegates for my table view, but I'm kinda lost on where to put my fetch code so the table view 1. has access to it and 2. uses the data returned from my fetch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You put the fetch code at that location of your program at which fetching is useful.
2. You store the data in a way that is convenient for you, probably a property typed array in your controller.
3. After fetching the data, you tell the table view, that there is new data to display by sending a [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstableview_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/reloadData) (et al.) message to it.
4. The [data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDataSource) of the table view, probably your controller will receive messages defined within the data source protocol to transport the date into the view. Since this is code written by you, too, it is totally under your controller, how you get the data. (See step 2).